# Kendo ui grid auto height

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am currently implementing the same kendoui grid as showing in the following:
http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/index.html

The problem that i can see is that the grid does not have auto height where if the record less than 10, the grid still in the same height.

Is there anyway i could resolve this since this one not happening when we use the previous version

I tried using the following javascript but still not working:

```
function resizeGrid() {
        var gridElement = $("#grid");
        var dataArea = gridElement.find(".k-grid-content");

        var newGridHeight = $(document).height() - 350;
        var newDataAreaHeight = newGridHeight - 65;

        dataArea.height(newDataAreaHeight);
        gridElement.height(newGridHeight);

        $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").refresh();
    }

    $(window).resize(function () {
        resizeGrid();
    });
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand your problem because the Grid actually has an *autoheight*. If in the definition of the Grid you define an attribute saying the number of pixel that grid should have, it will stick to that height no matter it it has 5 or 50 records. If it actually needs more space will add a scrollbar and if it need less, it will display the empty space.

In the example that you refer in your question try:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        data    : createRandomData(20),
        pageSize: 10
    },
    height    : 500,
    groupable : true,
    sortable  : true,
    pageable  : {
        refresh  : true,
        pageSizes: true
    },
    columns   : [
        { field: "FirstName", width: 90, title: "First Name" } ,
        { field: "LastName", width: 90, title: "Last Name" } ,
        { width: 100, field: "City" } ,
        { field: "Title" } ,
        { field   : "BirthDate", title   : "Birth Date", template: '#= kendo.toString(BirthDate,"dd MMMM yyyy") #' } ,
        { width: 50, field: "Age" }
    ]
});
```

And the height will be 500px.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ***css*** in order to draw a grid that will keep its height adjusted to its container, as well as considering other elements around:

```
#grid {
    /* chop the grid's height by 45px */
    height: calc(100% - 45px);
}

#grid .k-grid-content {
    /* chop the grid content's height by 25px */
    height: calc(100% - 25px) !important;
}
```

This is done without using the *'height'* property in the grid's declaration (at the .js side).

Works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Remove height: 500

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        data    : createRandomData(20),
        pageSize: 10
    },
    groupable : true,
    sortable  : true,
    pageable  : {
        refresh  : true,
        pageSizes: true
    },
    columns   : [
        { field: "FirstName", width: 90, title: "First Name" } ,
        { field: "LastName", width: 90, title: "Last Name" } ,
        { width: 100, field: "City" } ,
        { field: "Title" } ,
        { field   : "BirthDate", title   : "Birth Date", template: '#= kendo.toString(BirthDate,"dd MMMM yyyy") #' } ,
        { width: 50, field: "Age" }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, removing `scrollable` did the trick.
If there was only one row, the grid was small, and grew together with the amount of rows up to the pagesize level.
No height setting needed.